# Was there ever a plan for more titles in the The Fugitive/US Marshals universe?

Tags: sequels, the-fugitive, us-marshals

Watching [*The Fugitive* (1993)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106977/) today, I remembered [*US Marshals* (1998)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120873/) and how the US Marshal team is the same in both movies. I was happy when I found *US Marshals* was an official spin off of *The Fugitive* (I never honestly thought about it before) placing both films in the same universe.

What I haven't been able to find however is if there were ever any other films rumored/planned that involved Samuel Gerard and his team. Were there ever any other films planned? If not, is there a specific reason they never planned anything else? It seems that *US Marshals* did not do as well as *The Fugitive* did; is that what it boils down to?

Comment: It was [critically panned](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/us_marshals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, but...

There were rumors in 2015 that Warner Bros were planning on reviving the series, and [possibly casting Harrison Ford again](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/may/13/the-fugitive-new-sequel-coming), however this is only now evident on a few different websites, and [Harrison Ford's IMDB page](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000148/) only shows an unnamed Indiana Jones project as planned.

However, in November of 2019, it was announced that Warner Bros was rebooting the series, and has [tapped Albert Hughes](https://www.cbr.com/the-fugitive-warner-bros-reboot-albert-hughes/) to direct. There is also a Quibi short form series [starring Keifer Sutherland](https://deadline.com/2019/12/the-fugitive-quibi-natalie-martinez-brian-geraghty-genesis-rodriguez-keilani-arellanes-1202801918/) that is entirely separate upcoming.

So yes, it looks like it was once planned to have another in the series, but that has since been scrapped in favor of a reboot, with no release date estimated as of December 2019.

Comment: Thanks for that new series information! Will have to keep my ear to the ground!